# Database SQL: how to extract data from a sequence using regexp_substr?

Tags: postgresql

How to extract what is found after "ABC" from a json sequence using regexp_substr?

This is the sequence:

```
{"XXXX":?/,"XXXXX":XZX,"XXY":"EEE"}/,"WWW":{"ZZZ":{}},"HHHH":{"ABC":XXZ,"ASDD":4}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: "Behind" means "XXZ" or everything after "ABC"?

Comment: It is about "XXZ".

Comment: That isn't valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in JSON function:

```
SELECT your_json -> 'HHHH' ->> 'ABC'
```

(Notice that your example is not a wellformed JSON, so maybe you have to fix it before)